# Django Item Use Class

Tags: django

So in my application the user can use their items and it changes certain things in the database, however most actions would require different code.

An example would be an item could be used to add a month to the users account, another would change a variable on their profile.

I'm thinking the best was to do this is writing the code for each item use case (I guess you could use an eval and store in the DB but thats nasty). Heres what I have in my views

```
try:

    profile = request.user.profile
    inventory_item = Inventory.objects.get(id=inventory)

    if inventory_item.user == request.user:

        # some code here to use the item??
        useitem = ItemUse(inventory_item.item)

    else:

        messages.error(request, 'You cannot use an item you do not have')

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item_inventory'))

except Inventory.DoesNotExist:

    messages.error(request, 'No such item')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item_inventory'))
```

How would I be able to write some decent stable code? Any suggestions would be much appreciated (i've not written the ItemUse bit, thats what i'm asking the advice on for)

Comment: How do you know whether you should add a month to a users account or change a variable on their profile?

Comment: Each item will have a different use. some item uses will also need to delete database records.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know what to do in each case? Do you have a type field on the model, do you have different models for each item?

Comment: Well i'm thinking of just parsing the user and item into the class and managing it that way

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a solution, not sure if it makes much sense or is very scalable but here's what i've come up with:

```
class ItemUse:

def __init__(self, item, user):
    self.item = item
    self.user = user

def execute(self):
    try:

        getattr(self, self.item.slug)()
        Inventory.objects.remove(self.user, self.item, 1)
        return True

    except:
        return False    

def foo(self):

    self.user.profile.foo += 100
    self.user.profile.save(update_fields=['foo'])

    return True
```

This way I can parse the item and user and then test the execute method. Each method will correspond to the item slug value. It will do for now I guess